# Struts migration to Spring MVC - via Spring Boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, struts

We are in the initial stages of converting a Struts 1.2.9 application to Spring MVC. While the impact has been analyzed and well documented and understood for this migration, we are uncertain if we should introduce Spring Boot in this equation.

I have been reading other threads and would like to state that we are not looking to integrate Struts with Spring - rather we are for sure migrating and moving out of Struts to Spring MVC.

Given this background, invite suggestions/thoughts around below:

1. Benefit of introducing Spring Boot in this process is more of a distant one of an eventual move to Cloud. As such the team has completed the initial configuration required for a Spring application (like web.xml, required jars, spring-servlet.xml) and not sure of [immediate benefits](https://www.journaldev.com/7969/spring-boot-tutorial) for us.
2. In case we decide to use Spring Boot in this process, we perceive the impact to be:

   - i. Add spring-boot-starter-web to our gradle build.
   - ii. Create a starter Application class
   - iii. Revisit configurations in web.xml like startup servlets using '[SpringBootServletInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot)'
   - iv. Continue to use a war based [traditional deployment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) using gradle war plugin. Does this package the spring based libraries into the war or should the libraries be on the server classpath?

I welcome thoughts/suggestions/rejections of this as an approach itself :).

Comment: Not much seems to be discussed on this topic in [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=using+spring+boot+for+struts+to+spring+migration&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1).

Comment: [Article](https://qiita.com/miao1007/items/706d0a5ef10e7bdd6647) is the closest I got so far and am planning to try this. Shall keep this thread posted.

Comment: Hi Srini, we have similar situation and would like to understand how it went on your side . Recommendations, tips, suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: @Gopi - We successfully migrated our Struts application to Spring. I would recommend focusing on the migration than Spring-Boot as adding Spring-Boot once application is migrated to Spring is a trivial step.

Comment: thanks for the reply Srini. Appreciate your recommendation.